# MYSQL Fulltext Search Issue With Special Characters

Tags: php, mysql, boolean, escaping, full-text-search

I am doing a fulltext search in PHP in BOOLEAN mode, which is working 95% of the time. However when I enter a special character like ", the query fails.

The table in question holds around 6,000 records, with a large quantity being commercial grade fasteners.

Example Data:

> 7/16" UNF x 2 1/4" Hex

Before the query is performed, the input is cleaned using the following function

```
function clean($db, $str) {
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
}
$str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
$str = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$str);
return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $str);
}
```

When searching for 7/16" and nothing else, I should get a few hundred results but I'm getting nothing and I believe it's to do with how the input is being escaped incorrectly.

Once the input is cleaned I add + to the beginning of each word to ensure it is included in the results. This is done using the following:

```
$symbol = '+';
$string = $symbol . str_replace(' ', " $symbol", $term);
```

Example Query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (code, desc) AGAINST ('+7\/16\\\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY desc ASC
```

As you can see the original input of 7/16" has been changed to +7/16\\". Here is where I suspect the problem lies.

I'm really not sure what part of the clean function is causing this, I thought by adding ENT_NOQUOTES to htmlspecialchars would have resolved it but it hasn't.

Comment: 1. Get rid of `clean` function, that was a poor function for the `mysql_` library. You should be parameterizing your query. The `/` also shouldn't be escaped. Running `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (code, desc) AGAINST ('+7/16"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY desc ASC` on your DB interface gives back a result?

Comment: [Fulltext searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) is intended to work with words, not values like `7/16"`. You would probably get better results by checking for symbols in the search string and changing to a search using `LIKE` in those cases.

Comment: Full text search ignores punctuation, has stop words, and a word min.  The last two you can fiddle with the first I am not so sure about.

Comment: I'm surprised regarding the comment that the clean function being poor, are you able to elaborate on this at all or point me in the right direction?

Performing that search returns multiple values, the majority of them being correct, I.E beginning with 7/16". There are a couple of strange results but I'm not too concerned about those.

I think the first thing to do is to sort the sanitising function, hoping you can advise on that. Thanks

Comment: Have you set the collation to utf8_general_ci?

Comment: @McBern Yes the collation is set to utf8_general_ci. I've done some reading into parameterizing  my queries and realised this is a huge amount of work however it clearly needs to be done. Would the results be different if I was preapring my queries in the correct manner first?